# Cannot find executable in path for Visual C++ system call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to run `ping` in my Visual C++ program.

At the command line, typing `where ping` returns `C:\Windows\System32\PING.exe`. Furthermore, when I issue `ping` from the command line, it works from any directory. It seems to me that it's in my path.

However, when I try to run the following C++ program, I get an error.

```
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int pingretval = system("ping stackoverflow.com > /dev/null");
   std::cout << "Ping returns " << pingretval << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Ping returns 1
```

How can I make `system()` pick up the right executable?

**edit:** I changed `ping` to `C:\\Windows\\System32\\PING.exe` in the `system` argument, but it still gives the same error.

**edit 2:** I wasn't being completely truthful, SO; my sincere apologies. In my system call I was redirecting to `/dev/null` Linux style. I forgot to recompile after removing that bit, and the abscence of `/dev/null` in the Windows filesystem was the reason for the "cannot find the path specified" error. By removing the `> /dev/null`, this works just fine.

Comment: Perhaps your `PATH` environment variable is not set correctly.  Replace `ping` with `path` to see what it is.

Comment: What happen if you type "cmd /C ping stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: @CareyGregory: `system("path")` shows that `C:\Windows\system32` is indeed in the path. @manlio: That did not change the output.

Comment: `where ping` returns `C:\Windows\System32\PING.EXE` but `system("path")` shows `C:\Windows\system32` is in the path. Is this a matter of case sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Don't redirect to `/dev/null` for Windows.

Unfortunately, in my real application, I can't change the system call argument, which comes in the form of `ping -c 3 stackoverflow.com > /dev/null`. I was trying to make it kosher for Windows by making a wrapper to `ping` that ignores the `-c` switch (Linux only), but I forgot to change the Linux style redirection.

Comment: So near yet so far. If Microsoft had used the name `null` instead of `nul`, it would work on both platforms by simply creating the `dev` directory on Windows.